# recursive search and push in complex array/object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lodash

i have taken this plunker  https://plnkr.co/edit/CIGAA5BmiKU4hCMsOaIB?p=preview this as a reference but now i need dynamic array operation

```
[
{
    title: 'Menu 1',
    id :1,
    hide : true,
    children: [],
},
{
    title: 'Menu 2',
    hide : true,
    id :2,
    children: [{
        title: 'Sub Menu 2',
        hide : true,
        id :3,
        children: [{
            title: 'Sub Sub Menu 2',
            hide : true,
            id :4,
            children: [{
                title: 'Sub Sub Menu 2, Sibling 1',
                hide : true,
                id :6,
                children: []
            },
            {
                title: 'Sub Sub Sub Menu 2, Sibling 2',
                hide : true,
                id :12,
                children: []
            }]
        }]
    }]

},
{
    title: 'Menu 3',
    hide : true,
    id :14,
    children: []
}
];
```

now I have to push children in object having id 6 and need updated whole object after every operation.

I am using angular 5

I have used this following method

```
find(id, items,newData) {
  var i = 0, found;
  for (; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].id === id) {
      items[i].children=newData;
      return items;
} else if (_.isArray(items[i].children)) {
  found = this.find(id, items[i].children,newData);
  if (found) {
    return false;

      }
    }
  }
}
```

here basically the newData is that array that i need to push ,
items is the my main object that should be updated after push

please correct me if somewhere I am wrong.also if element having id 3 has children having id 4. so now if it should not be pushed in the same parent id.

all objects have same structure like newData has also children

Comment: I don't really understand the logic in your code

Answer (score 0):

Create & use a recursive function

```js
var arr = [{
  title: 'Menu 1',
  id: 1,
  hide: true,
  children: [],
}, {
  title: 'Menu 2',
  hide: true,
  id: 2,
  children: [{
    title: 'Sub Menu 2',
    hide: true,
    id: 3,
    children: [{
      title: 'Sub Sub Menu 2',
      hide: true,
      id: 4,
      children: [{
        title: 'Sub Sub Menu 2, Sibling 1',
        hide: true,
        id: 6,
        children: [{
          title: 'Sub Sub Menu 2, Sibling 1',
          hide: true,
          id: 7,
          children: []
        }]
      }, {
        title: 'Sub Sub Sub Menu 2, Sibling 2',
        hide: true,
        id: 12,
        children: []
      }]
    }]
  }]
}, {
  title: 'Menu 3',
  hide: true,
  id: 14,
  children: []
}];

// a recursive function which accepts an array and the id , this id will be use to target the children of the object whose id matches
// looping through the array & checking if id matches
function findUpdate(array, id) {
  array.forEach(function(elem) {
    if (elem.id === id) {
      // push value to children of that object
      elem.children.push("pushed")
    } else {
       //check if children is an array and if it is empty
      if (Array.isArray(elem.children) && elem.children.length > 0) {
        //call the same function with the new arra
        findUpdate(elem.children, id)
      }
    }
  });

  console.log(arr)
}

console.log(findUpdate(arr, 12))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning false not item.You want to replace or push.

```js
var id = 6;
var items = [{
        title: 'Menu 1',
        id: 1,
        hide: true,
        children: [],
    },
    {
        title: 'Menu 2',
        hide: true,
        id: 2,
        children: [{
            title: 'Sub Menu 2',
            hide: true,
            id: 3,
            children: [{
                title: 'Sub Sub Menu 2',
                hide: true,
                id: 4,
                children: [{
                        title: 'Sub Sub Menu 2, Sibling 1',
                        hide: true,
                        id: 6,
                        children: [{
                            title: 'Sub Sub Menu 2, Sibling 1',
                            hide: true,
                            id: 7,
                            children: []
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Sub Sub Sub Menu 2, Sibling 2',
                        hide: true,
                        id: 12,
                        children: []
                    }
                ]
            }]
        }]

    },
    {
        title: 'Menu 3',
        hide: true,
        id: 14,
        children: []
    }
];
var newData = [{
    title: 'new Data'
}]
var find = (id, items, newData) => {
    var i = 0,
        found;
    for (; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i].id === id) {
            items[i].children.push(newData); //change here if you want add in existing array
            return items;
        } else if (items[i].children.length != 0) {
            found = this.find(id, items[i].children, newData);
            if (found) {
                return items;
            }
        }
    }
    return items;
}

console.log(find(id, items, newData))
```

Comment: i want to push array in children of particular id , in the end i need final updated  whole array.

Comment: no check the response you have updated is not in children array. new object that need to pushed is also having same structure as other elements have.